# MongoDB date insert

Tags: mongodb, date, nosql, schema

This is my schema:

```
db.createCollection("user_clicks", {
 validator: {
 $jsonSchema: {
 bsonType: "object",
 required: [ "session_id", "country", "browser", "url", "date"],
 properties: {
 session_id: {
 bsonType: "string",
 description: "must be a string and is required" },
 country: {
 bsonType: "string",
 description: "country name and is required"},
 browser: {
 bsonType: "string",
 description: "browser name and is required"},
 url : {
 bsonType: "string",
 description: "user click url and is required"},
 date: {
 bsonType: "date",
 description: "localdatetime and is required"}}}})
```

This is the code I am using to generate data:

```
mgeneratejs `{
  "session_id": "$oid",
  "country": "$country",
  "browser": {
    "$choose": {
      "from": [
        "Firefox",
        "Chrome",
        "Safari",
        "Explorer"
      ],
      "weights": [
        1,
        2,
        2,
        1
      ]
    }
  },
  "url": {
    "$choose": {
      "from": [
        "google.com/images",
        "facebook.com/profile1538713",
        "soundcloud.com/playlist03",
        "some-url.com/home",
        "sinoptik.ua/kyiv"
      ],
      "weights": [
        1,
        2,
        2,
        1,
        3
      ]
    }
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "min": "2016-08-01T23:59:59.999Z",
      "max": "2016-10-01T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
  }
}` -n 5 | mongoimport --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/events" --collection user_clicks --mode=insert
```

I'm trying to generate random date by using mgeneratejs and mongoimport. The problem is that i can't insert any date like : **"3/13/2019"** or **"2019-03-26T23:44:26Z"** (that's what i actually need). The error is:

```
**WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})**
```

I try to insert like `new Date("2019-03-26T23:44:26Z")` and it works! Please help how to automate every time inserting create new Date(date) or how to fix this !

Comment: What does the code you're using to generate the data you are trying to import look like?

Comment: @MattOestreich , it looks like: ```mgeneratejs '{"session_id": "$oid" , "country": "$country",
"browser": {"$choose": {"from": ["Firefox","Chrome","Safari","Explorer"],
"weights": [1,2,2,1]}},
"url": {"$choose": {"from": ["google.com/images","facebook.com/profile1538713",
"soundcloud.com/playlist03","some-url.com/home","sinoptik.ua/kyiv"],
"weights":
[1,2,2,1,3]}},
"date": {"$date": {"min": "2016-08-01T23:59:59.999Z", "max":
"2016-10-01T23:59:59.999Z"}}}' -n 5  | 
 mongoimport  --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/events" --collection user_clicks --mode=insert```

Comment: @MattOestreich , also i used service to generate random date in csv/json format and it doesn't work too.. maybe something wrong with schema ? am i done right with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused at what your issue is... everything is working as it should.. You store dates in `Mongo` as `Date` objects (that have the type of `Date`)..

If you want to store dates in `Mongo` in a format like `3/13/2019` you can do something like this:

```
// javascript
let dateToInsert = new Date("3/13/2019");
```

Comment: so you tried and it work for you ? All i did was use db , create schema and try to insert...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below before inserting the random date and it should work:

```
new Date(randomDate);
```